# Passing information between pages with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass information between pages.

I would usually just use sessions in plain PHP. I wonder if there is a more correct way to do this on Laravel.

### First_page.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION["ID"] = 'item_id';

?>
```

### Second_page.php

```
<?php

session_start();


echo $_SESSION['ID'];
#"item_id"


?>
```

How is this supposed to be done in Laravel?

Comment: Sessions are intended for that, also in laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Session.

```
Session::flash(); //or Session::put

Session::flash('values', $passvalues);     
Redirect::to('/add1');

$oldinput = Session::get('values');
```

Answer (score 2):

In laravel you can pass a variable in your url i.e. :

In routes.php

```
 Route::get('/page1', 'YourController@Yourfunction');
 Route::get('/page2/{id}', 'YourController@loadpage2');
```

In your controller.php

```
public function Yourfunction(){
   return view('page1');
}

public function loadpage2(id){

   return view('page2', compact('id'));

}
```

in your view have a link to url  `/page2/3` where 3 is your id

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use session then you need to do 2 things.

1. save session variables in your controller
2. display session variables in your view

In your controller you can use something like

```
session()->put('your_session_variable','some value');
```

In your view then you can display that session variable

```
@if(session()->has('your_session_variable'))  
{{Session::get('your_session_varible',"session_not_set(default value)") }}
@endif
```

Its good to use default value for displaying session variables (many times that session variable is not set).